# push a UIViewController when received a remote notification

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

The project's initial viewController is a *UITabBarViewController*, I want to push a new viewController when received a remote notification, but not sure now which viewController is in, how to deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily determine which `UIViewController` is visible currently, see below, considering code is written in `AppDelegate` to access `UIWindow` property directly

```
UITabBarController *tabController=(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

UINavigationController *selectedNav=(UINavigationController *)tabController.selectedViewController;

UIViewController *viewControllerVisible=[[selectedNav viewControllers] lastObject];
```

Then upto you what you want to do.

Hope this helps.

Cheers.